# Make checkbox more responsive react native redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have checkboxes in my app and am updating their values as a user checks/un-checks them. I am doing this via redux by dispatching an action.

```
onChangeDetails: (serverReport, details) => {
  dispatch(editDetails(serverReport.uuid, details))
}
```

There is a short lag in the checkbox click as the new value is being saved. I want to have this check occur right away, without the lag.

I know I could store the value in state and add a save button to the page, but I'd rather keep it as is. I've seen this done in other apps, but am not sure the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

> I would suggest is you can check/uncheck using the `local state` and also `dispatch` the action to update the `reducer` i.e global state to be used by other components.. Something like this,

```
onChangeDetails: (serverReport, details) => {
  //Use local state to update the UI to avoid lag.
  this.setState({
    checked: !this.state.checked
  })

  //Also dispatch action to update the reducer.
  dispatch(editDetails(serverReport.uuid, details))
}
```

This should avoid lag, as when you try to update the state by dispatching an action, it takes some time to mutate the state. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Dev! I guess my question would be what happens if the dispatch fails?

Comment: @MollyHarper, n why would that happen. If it happens then I think you might be doing something wrong in the reducer code, which should be avoided. It might only happen if there is any async API operation involved

Comment: If I only use local state on that page the page won't be updated when an element is updated elsewhere in the app. And if I update local state when receiving new props it can sometimes wrongly change the state. For example if I check two checkboxes quickly sometimes the there'll be a brief period where the second checkbox becomes unchecked. This happens because of the delay in receiving the updated props from the first and second dispatches.